# Release iOS build error - Use of undeclared identifier 'Twitter'

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-twitter-signin

I am using react-native-twitter sign in, and followed all the steps in the official documentation, but getting

Use of undeclared identifier 'Twitter' in AppDelegate.m file

this error while Archiving the IOS app, but it works fine while running on simulator, what should be the problem ?

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar issue. Running dev version on iOS simulator works fine, but when I try to archive app in XCode, I got `Use of undeclared identifier` error.

## Solution

In `AppDelegate.m` file, find header files you included:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
#import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
#import <FlipperKitLayoutPlugin/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin/FKUserDefaultsPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>
#import <SKIOSNetworkPlugin/SKIOSNetworkAdapter.h>
#import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h>

#import <Some/Dependency.h> <--- ❌ this might be the problem
```

If you've imported your dependency under this line:

```
#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
```

please move them up to before it.

For example:

```
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <Some/Dependency.h> <--- ✅ Right here

#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
#import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
#import <FlipperKitLayoutPlugin/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin/FKUserDefaultsPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>
#import <SKIOSNetworkPlugin/SKIOSNetworkAdapter.h>
#import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h>
```

### Reason

FB Sonar Kit or Flipper is a debugging tool. It might get disabled when archiving.

Comment: This was exactly my mistake. Many thanks, I won't repeat it