# React native - Use of undeclared identifier 'RCTDevLoadingView'

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I just updated Xcode (to version 12.5 (12E262)) and got this error in my react native project.

I searched everywhere, but I have not found anything and I do not have any experience with Swift/Objective-C to solve it myself.

here is a screenshot if it helps:
[image]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5):

It might be due to the import statement for `<React/RCTDevLoadingView.h>` being placed below the block of imports after `#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED`, [which might have been disabled when building/archiving](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66496297/12937056).

Check out the link above to find out the proper way to import your dependencies - it should always be above `#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED`.

EDIT: I recently encountered this exact issue after upgrading to Xcode 13.